# Proper procedures for reconnecting WebRTC Peer connection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc

I'm developing a group voice chat application using WebRTC and React.

I have managed to establish a connection and the voice chat works fine on first connection.

The way it works is like this:

1. User A joins chat room.
2. User B joins chat room.
3. User A enables audio through a toggle button - this notifies the signaling server that they're open for any WebRTC connections.
4. User B enables audio through a toggle button - they now through the server establish the WebRTC connection process to anyone who has enabled audio (being user A in this case).

This has worked fine so far. My issue is establishing a connection a second time around in the scenario of:

1. Both users have audio enabled. Voice comms working fine.
2. User B toggles audio - disabling it. User A remains active.
3. User B toggles audio again to reconnect to user A.

I get the following error:

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called in wrong state: kStable
```

I understand this error means that there's an issue with the connection order. So I figured this could be to do with not having a adequate disconnection process.

So I implemented a feature that when User B disables audio, it sends all other users in the room a message to remove that persons Peer_Connection object from the peer conection array on each users local state. But this is to no avail.

I'm confused as to why this is happening because if I exit the chat room and re-enter on both users, the connection can be re-established once more, so I assume it has something to do with there being remnants of the old connection causing issues with the new.

(It also works if both users have audio enabled, the one disables, leaves the room, comes back and enables all while the first user had it enabled the whole time. So an error on part with the client who sends the offer?)

As always, any tips and help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Reconnection was not possible. For anyone seeking a solution for a similar issue:

Instead of reconnection, simple disable the audiotracks. Locally this means no one gets any audio feed from you. Disabling remote audiotracks mutes the audio for yourself obviously. Muting both means there's no audio coming in or out, which can simulate a disconnection with a toggle switch while the person remains in the same room.